# Postgres_Failover Not Working

Tags: postgresql

I was able to configure and Replicate between master and Slave ,so when we insert anything on master db it will automatically replicate to slave,

Now,requirement is that if we shutdown master can we able to proceds with slave as master.

i was followed this link for replication

http://searchadmin.org/Thread-ha-postgresql-cluster-by-streaming-replication-pgpool-ii/

Comment: ... and the problem is?

Comment: Have look at repmgr. It is a really cool tool that makes setting up replication and doing the failover *much* easier.